# "...like after you have your loved one pass away" - what tense is this?

Tags: idioms, aspect

I found this sentence in *From Memories* by Sarah White. Is it correct? I think the tense is a bit strange here.

> She looked sad like after you have your loved one pass away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence grammatically (except that it would be clearer if there were a comma after *sad*), but it is written in a very colloquial register, and it employs *have* in a way you may not be familiar with.

- The colloquial part is the use of *like* where formal English would employ *as*. The *like* phrase compares the woman’s sadness to what you, the reader, might feel after a particular sort of experience. The experience, the object of *after*, may be expressed as a noun, as a gerund clause, or as a finite-verb clause

  Here are examples of the construction with a noun and a gerund phrase (they're from the first page of a Google search on "sad like after"):

  > ... feeling sad—like after a lousy day at the office or a fight with someone you love
  >   It's a good sad, like after watching a really tragic movie and you've just cried your eyes out while eating an entire box of chocolates

  Here are examples with a finite verb in the past tense.

  > He was still sad—like after you left
  >   I feel sad (like after we lost the girls)

  Those two have the verb in the past tense because *sad* is compared to the feeling prompted by a specific past event. But the verb can also be cast in the present tense if you compare *sad* to a ‘generic’ event which occurs repeatedly or might occur at any time:

  > ... sad like after you get dumped by someone you didn’t really care about
  >   ... sad like when you pass a cemetery, seeing all those lonely gravestones

  That's the sort of construction that's involved in your example.
- The other thing that could be confusing you here is the use of *have*, which may feel to you like the beginning of a perfect construction. It's actually something quite different:  neither a perfect auxiliary nor a causative auxiliary (as in *to have something done*) but the lexical verb used to mean “experience” or “suffer” and taking as its direct object a non-finite clause with a bare infinitive (an infinitive not marked with *to*) as its head. Thus:

  > She had her house burn down = She experienced her house burning down.

  In the same way, *you have your loved one pass away* means “you experience your loved one passing away”.